# Not showing map using Gmaps,js plugin

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am getting latitude and longitude data from PHP the code below shows how i created the JSON data.

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_seen_query)){

    $arr[] = array(

        "lat" => $row['lat'],
        "lang" => $row['lang'],
        "last_push" => $row['last_push']

    );

}

$json = json_encode($arr);

echo $json;
```

Then this is the JSON result.

```
[{"lat":"-17.7462033","lang":"31.0718699","last_push":"2016-02-12 11:47:22"}]
```

Then on my web page where i want to display the page this is the code.

```
        $('.last_seen_locale').on('click', function(){
        var uuid = $('.id-ref').attr('data-uuid');
        var map;
        var mylat;
        var mylong;
         var locationCoordinates = [];

        $.post('process_device.php', {uuid: uuid, displayMap:displayMap}, function(data){
            //locationCoordinates = $.parseJSON(data);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                mylat = data[i].lat;
                mylong = data[i].lang;
            }

            map = new GMaps({
               div: '.map',
               lat: mylat,
               lng: mylong,
               zoom: 14

            });

            map.addMarker({
              lat: mylat,
              lng: mylong,
              title: 'Muzinda',
              click: function(e) {
                alert('You clicked in this marker');
              }
            });


        });
```

So if i run this code in web browser, Firefox Debug Is displaying this error: "uncaught exception: No latitude or longitude defined".
I don't know where i am going wrong.Your solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem might be because your JSON response has the latitude and longitude as strings, e.g. `"-17.7462033"`.  Google Maps expects floating point numbers, not strings.  I've no idea how the gmaps.js plugin deals with these, but you might have more luck casting them to numbers, e.g. `mylat = parseFloat(data[i].lat)`

Comment: Thanks @duncan unfortunately it didn't work.I greatly appreciate you help.

Comment: I have tried to put static latitude and longitude data it displays the map and the marker well. I am still scratching my head to see the error.@duncan

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` look like inside your AJAX callback?

Comment: Hy Duncan i managed to solve the problem, i realized that i should put the PHP query file on its on.My PHP and Ajax where running on the same page that's why i was getting an error on callback.The Ajax code is perfect.